# has_and_belongs_to_many relationship in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to make a website for a tennis coach using ruby on rails. I am completely new to this and I am struggling with some of the terminology. The website has a login system where users can sign in and then sign up for different events that the tennis coach has created. So basically the users can go to many events and the events can have many users attending. I have made a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship between my users table and events table and the code is below:

Here is my migration:

```
class CreateEventsUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
      create_table :events_users, :id => false do |t|
        t.integer :event_id
        t.integer :user_id
      end

      add_index :events_users, :event_id
      add_index :events_users, :user_id 
      add_index :events_users, [:event_id, :user_id]
    end

    def self.down
      drop_table :events_users
    end
end
```

Here are my models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

Here is my event form:

```
    <li>
    <%= link_to event.title, event %>
  | <%= link_to "delete", event, method: :delete %>

  | *insert sign up here*

   </li>
```

Basically my question is, how would I make a form and a controller that would let a signed in user, sign up for one of the events in the database? I have been stuck on this for days. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This should be as simple as `Event.find(id).users << current_user`.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried making the user select a checkbox with the events that they wanted to go to using the tutorial at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p5NAdY4Bmjg but this wasn't really what I wanted. Each event has its own page and I wanted a list of users that signed up to an event, on each event page.

Comment: I havent tried but if the post data of the format user[events] = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}] and with the code User.new(params[:user]).save will it not work?

Comment: @Saravanan - It will not. This will: `user[:events_ids] = [1,2]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a has_many through instead of using has_and_belongs_to for scalability issues and is a suggested practice. Coming to your requirement, I did a similar thing but with users following other users and tried to adopt some of them for your requirement.

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many : Relationship
  has_many : users, :through => :Relationships
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :Relationship
  has_many :events, :through => :Relationships

  //define other methods//
  def follow!(event_id)
    relationships.create!(event_id: event.id)
  end
end

class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :event_id      
  belongs_to :events
  belongs_to :users
end
```

You need to create the relationship migration like this

```
class CreateRelationships < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
    create_table :relationships do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :event_id
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :relationships, :user_id
    add_index :relationships, :event_id
    add_index :relationships, [:user_id, :event_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

You can try adding a button on the events page view like this.

```
<%= form_for(current_user.relationships.build(evnt_id: @user.id)) do |f| %>
    <div><%= f.hidden_field :event_id %></div>
    <%= f.submit "Follow", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
   <% end %>
```

Relationship controller can be something like this.

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
    def create
     @user = User.find(params[:relationship][:event_id])
     current_user.follow!(@user)
     respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
     end
    end
  end
```

This tutorial was very helpful for me in developing the application for users to follow other users. Hope it will help you too. Good luck !!
http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#top

Comment: This is almost perfect for me except I am using rails 4 so I cant use the attr_accessible code. Would I have to add: 
    **private
     def relationship_params
      params.require(:relationship).permit(:event_id)
     end**

Comment: Yes thats right. We have to use strong attributes if you are using Rails 4. Add the above in your EventsController. Please refer this if for strong parameters [link](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't discovered it already, you are in for a real treat if you checkout railscasts from Ryan Bates. Here is a tutorial on using checkboxes in a form with a HABTM association--actually he suggests, and you should consider it, moving to has_many, through relationship instead of HABTM.

Regardless, it should at least give you an idea of how you can make it work in your app. http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes-revised. That episode may require a membership, however, the $9 bux/month is totally reasonable for what you're getting.

Comment: I looked at an earlier version of this video but I am trying to move away from check boxes. Instead I want a sign up button and when the user presses it, they will be added to the related event. I will give the has_many relationship a try though.